# Vim Insert Mode on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, vim

Apparently Mac keyboards don't have an <kbd>Insert</kbd> key (or maybe they do but I can't find it). How can I get to insert mode in **vim** on a Mac?

Comment: The great thing about vim is that it's designed to be used on a simple keyboard with nothing more than the alphanum keys and control and escape.  It's great for touch typists because you never have to remove your hands from the home row.

Comment: I learned something different from this question -- The \<kdb\> tag.

Answer (score 256, accepted):

If this is as simple a question as it seems, you merely press <kbd>i</kbd>.

Comment: Great, thanks! I must admit, I'm both a vim newbie and a mac newbie so yeah, it was simple as that. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, well if you want some useful tips on vim, I suggest looking for "cheat sheets" online.  Also, the $ % and ^ locations are your friend, and great time savers. Use them in combination with commands editing (delete, move, copy).

Comment: Also the :help files within vim are endlessly comprehensive

Comment: The vimtutor is also great for newbies. Simply type vimtutor on the command line, see also :help tutor

Comment: LMAO. It seems like such a simple question, but I too was very lost. Hard to search for as well. I've always used the insert key. I was at a loss.

Comment: Just want to express my hate on Mac usability, it suck so much!

Answer (score 21):

Vim enters the insert mode using <kbd>i</kbd> (or <kbd>a</kbd> for append), regardless of platform. Overwrite mode is only rarely entered using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>. I've never used the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key here.

Answer (score 10):

The other use of the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key is to switch between replace-mode and insert-mode when already in either.  You can accomplish this easily on the Mac by just mapping another key to do this for you.  In your `~/.vimrc` just put `imap <F13> <Insert>` and now the <kbd>F13</kbd> key (which on my Mac keyboard is the closest key to where the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key is on a regular keyboard).

Comment: But it may be easier to let people remember R is the key to enter replace-mode in vim without any configurations.

Comment: My answer was about when you're already in insert/replace mode, in that mode if you hit `R` then it will type an `R` into the buffer.

Comment: You are absolutely right. However, I am not sure everybody knows. As I came from the Windows background, I knew how to enter the replace-mode with Insert earlier than R.

Comment: When I press F13 after adding this to my `.vimrc` it works as a per-word case/capitalization change - any ideas why?

Comment: Perhaps something else maps `F13` (do you see the capitalization behavior without my mapping?), or perhaps `Insert` is mapped elsewhere (use `inoremap` instead of `imap` to fix this).

Answer (score 7):

Pressing "i" brings you into insert mode within VIM.

Answer (score 7):

Enter Insert Mode: press <kbd>i</kbd>

Exit Insert Mode: press <kbd>esc</kbd>, type <kbd>:x</kbd>